# Use == for comparison if enum only on one side

Tags: java, enums, equals

If an enum constant is compared with something else, is it permissible to use `==` in place of the `equals` method?

Example (`User` implements the interface `IUser`):

```
IUser peter = User.PETER;
if (User.PETER == peter) {
// do something
}
```

Comment: Well, what is IUser?

Comment: Yes. This is a *guarantee* enforced by the JLS. There is only one instance for each enum constant. But if more classes implement the `IUser` interface, well, then this doesn't apply, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code we assume that your enumeration *User* implements interface *IUser*. Otherwise the code *IUser peter = User.PETER;* would compile.

Yes, it is safe. Because in the class loader there can be a *single* instance of each enumeration. This means, there can be only a *single* instance of each enumeration value. These values cannot be created by some other mechanism. That's why if there are two variables representing the same enumeration value, it must *be the same* instance. That's why simple comparison by *==* is sufficient.

Comment: But the OP isn't just comparing enum constants, they're also comparing `IUser` objects to enum constants, and `IUser` could be implemented by any class

Comment: @user: *they're also comparing IUser* - no. Where do you read that?

Comment: It says `IUser peter = User.PETER;` I took that to mean that `peter` could be anything, not just a `User`. Couldn't it also be a `Foo` if Foo implements IUser?

Comment: The "enum only on one side" in the title seems like a strong indication that the other side doesn't have to be an enum.

Comment: OK. Anyway. enumeration value can only be equal if this is *the same instance* . To check if this is the same instance it is **sufficient** co compare via *==*.